# Cannot find go package inside submodule

Tags: git, go, git-submodules

I may be doing this quite wrongly, so I hope this makes sense.

Setup:
`GOPATH=/Users/alex/go`

I have a project called k-cpi-release located in my GOPATH (i.e., located at /Users/alex/go/src/k-cpi-release. There is a submodule located inside that project at cpi-release/src/github.company.com/team/cpi (i.e., full path is /Users/alex/go/src/k-cpi-release/src/github.company.com/team/k-cpi). I run `git submodule update --init --recursive` to get that repository.

Inside that submodule, the code is located at k-cpi/cmd/cpi (full path /Users/alex/go/src/k-cpi-release/src/github.company.com/team/k-cpi/cmd/cpi). When I cd to that directory with the code and run `go build`, I get the following error for several packages:

```
main.go:13:2: cannot find package "github.company.com/team/k-cpi/actions" in any of:
/Users/alex/go/src/k-cpi-release/src/github.company.com/team/k-cpi/vendor/github.company.com/team/k-cpi/actions (vendor tree)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.company.com/team/k-cpi/actions (from $GOROOT)
/Users/alex/go/src/github.company.com/team/k-cpi/actions (from $GOPATH)
```

What I infer is that the search the package looks in GOPATH and the vendor folder, but the repository is not located in either place because it is a submodule.

How can this be remedied?

Comment: Why can't it be in a `vendor/` folder?

Comment: I'm working with another person's repository. The design is not my choice.

Comment: But you're changing the import path of the code, so that is your choice. You've changed the `k-cpi` package's import path to `k-cpi-release/src/github.company.com/team/k-cpi`. I don't understand why you're putting a submodule in your package if you're not trying to vendor it.